# asp.net ajax control toolkit combobox displays incorectly when in fieldset with style of position:relative

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I currently have an Instance of the ASP.net ajax control toolkit combo box residing in a field set with a style of  position:releative applied. The control also sits in a very plain table (please no comments about using tables for lay-out, I know it is evil and try to avoid it).

There are two problems with the display of the list:

1. The list does not sit flush with the text box. In I.E. 7 (which is the majority of my target audience, intranet where IE7 is the company standard) the list display about 10px below the fieldset, which is what the bottom margin of the fieldset is set to. In FF 2.0 the list sits sinificantly lower and off-set to the right.
2. Below the filed set there is more content in a div, also with a style of position:relative applied. The list from the combo box displays behind the content of this div, which is obviouly an issue.

Removing position:releative from the fieldset resolves the display issue of the combo box, but results in other unwanted display side effects.

My interim workaround is to specifically restyle this fieldset without the position:absolute style, but I'm hoping for a better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon,

There are hard-coded styles for this Combobox that really make display issues/CSS styling a nightmare.

I actually downloaded the source code and stripped out all of the out-of-the-box styling and recompiled a new DLL to use and doing that has really made me happy.

If you want to go this route, I'll be happy to share what files I adjusted and what I removed.

Comment: And what was that files that you have adjusted??? And what you where removed??? If you please??? because I'm facing the same issue... the dropdown menu open in "out in space" area...